# Can memory compaction cause a high perceived memory usage?

Tags: docker, memory-usage

This is a bit of a long shot, but we're currently experiencing some issues with one of our Dockerized Java applications: [Stackoverlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77763873/docker-kills-java-container-due-to-oom-but-no-signs-of-high-memory-usage-in-jmx)

We've set the docker memory limit to 2GB, which is way beyond what the java application could ever use, so I'm really looking for any possible cause of this issue.

Is it possible that during memory defragmentation/compaction, the system reports a higher memory usage for the application for which it's doing those operations (on it's allocated memory) and thus it triggers docker's OOM killer ?

Some more information of one of the EC2 servers

cat /proc/pagetypeinfo

```
Page block order: 9
Pages per block:  512

Free pages count per migrate type at order       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10
Node    0, zone      DMA, type    Unmovable      1      0      0      1      2      1      1      0      1      0      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Movable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      3
Node    0, zone      DMA, type  Reclaimable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type    Unmovable   2160   1450    509    358     72      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type      Movable  39753  18110   3832    317     88     18      2      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type  Reclaimable    479    970      7      6      3      0      1      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type    Unmovable     72    410    350      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type      Movable 132228  61046   1635      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type  Reclaimable      0      2      7      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type   HighAtomic      2      0     15     11      7      2      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

Number of blocks type     Unmovable      Movable  Reclaimable   HighAtomic      Isolate
Node 0, zone      DMA            1            7            0            0            0
Node 0, zone    DMA32           59         1391           78            0            0
Node 0, zone   Normal          448         5888          127            1            0
```

cat /proc/sys/vm/extfrag_threshold

```
500
```

cat /sys/kernel/debug/extfrag/extfrag_index

```
Node 0, zone      DMA -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000
Node 0, zone    DMA32 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 0.988 0.994 0.997 0.999
Node 0, zone   Normal -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 0.979 0.990 0.995 0.998 0.999
```

free -h

```
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         11G        1.5G        1.2M        2.4G        3.7G
Swap:          4.0G        907M        3.1G
```

We only have this issue on our production servers (which have been running for almost a year), our lower environments stop every weekend and we haven't managed to trigger this issue manually so far. Nevertheless we're going to try to replace the servers next week, hoping that this issue is far less likely to happen.

I know it's a long shot, I'm not an expert when it comes to Linux memory management and it's probably very unlikely to be the root cause, but it's a question for which I'd love to know the answer.